# Where to instantiate shared thread objects in Django, equiv of pyramid registry?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, pyramid, wsgi

I'm plugging some framework agnostic code of mine into Django instead of Pyramid. It uses SQLAlchemy and has a customized session factory object for getting db sessions. In pyramid, I instantiate this at server start up in the main app method and attach it to the registry so that all other parts of my app can get at it. I'd like to know what the "correct" way of instantiating and making available a shared factory is in Django. Is there somewhere canonical for putting something like that so that Django users will find it easily and the code will be readable to people used to Django patterns?

thanks

Comment: Outside of the `settings` module there isn't anything fitting a pattern in Django, I don't think.

Comment: Why not in `__init__.py` of your module? as applications are added adding appropriate string to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, your can be sure that module will be imported on startup and nessessary objects will be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks alko, which __init__.py would that be? in the top level of the django app? will it have access to the settings dict?

Answer (score 0):

I place my SQLAlchemy/SQLSoup connections at `models.py`, because it is related to persistence (and to the "model" layer of Model-View-Whatever).

You can even replace the Django ORM with SQLAlchemy if you are not using applications relying on the first like `django.contrib.admin` or `django.contrib.auth`.